# Linked server databases are only consists of Tables and Views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, linked-server

I have created a linked server in SQL server 2016 but I can only see tables and views under linked server databases (No stored procedures).

[image]

When I try to execute a procedure at the linked server using EXECUTE AT command I'm getting a

> Could not find stored procedure"

error. But I can select tables using `[ServerName].[DBName].dbo.[TableName]`.

Is there any missing configuration in order to get stored procedures?

Comment: What happens if you use `OPENQUERY` ? Does the stored procedure return 0,1, or multiple result sets?

Comment: Linked server connections don't have to allow stored procedure access. Do the properties of your linked server connection have RPC and RPC Out enabled? See [sp_helpserver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helpserver-transact-sql)

Comment: Preben Huybrechts The stored procedure only returns one result set. OPENQERY is also returning "Could not find stored procedure" error.

Yes I have enabled RPC and RPC Out properties?